# Parallel processing with dependencies on a SGE cluster

Tags: parallel-processing, qsub

I'm doing some experiments on a computing cluster. My algorithm has two steps. The first one writes its outputs to some files which will be used by the second step. The dependecies are 1 to n meaning one step2 programs needs the output of n step1 program. I'm not sure what to do neither waist cluster resources nor keep the head node busy. My current solution is:

submit script (this runs on the head node)

```
for different params, p:
    run step 1 with p

sleep some time based on the an estimate of how much step 1 takes

for different params, q:
    run step 2 with q
```

step 2 algorithm (this runs on the computing nodes)

```
while files are not ready:
    sleep a few minutes
do the step 2
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

SGE provides both job dependencies and array jobs for that. You can submit your phase 1 computations an array job and then submit the phase 2 computation as a dependent job using the `qsub -hold_jid <phase 1 job ID|name> ...`. This will make the phase 2 job wait until all the phase 1 computations have finished and then it will be released and dispatched. The phase 1 computations will run in parallel as long as there are enough slots in the cluster.

In a submission script it might be useful to specifiy holds by job name and name each array job in a unique way. E.g.

```
mkdir experiment_1; cd experiment_1
qsub -N phase1_001 -t 1-100 ./phase1
qsub -hold_jid phase1_001 -N phase2_001 ./phase2 q1
cd ..
mkdir experiment_2; cd experiment_2
qsub -N phase1_002 -t 1-42 ./phase1 parameter_file
qsub -hold_jid phase1_002 -N phase2_002 ./phase2 q2
cd ..
```

This will schedule 100 executions of the `phase1` script as the array job `phase1_001` and another 42 executions as the array job `phase1_002`. If there are 142 slots on the cluster, all 142 executions will run in parallel. Then one execution of the `phase2` script will be dispatched after all tasks in the `phase1_001` job have finished and one execution will be dispatched after all tasks in the `phase1_002` job have finished. Again those can run in parallel.

Each taks in the array job will receive a unique `$SGE_TASK_ID` value ranging from 1 to 100 for the tasks in job `phase1_001` and from 1 to 42 for the tasks in job `phase1_002`. From it you can compute the `p` parameter.